# Collapsing Toolbar Layout - full height Image and scrolled at start

Tags: android, scroll, android-appcompat

I have got a layout quite similar to this one: http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/ - a classic approach to the Collapsing Toolbar.
I would like to extend it with following feature:

The ImageView is full screen height and at activity starts it is automatically scrolled half of it height down. When activity starts and user will scroll down, it will behave the old way, but (at activity starts) when he scrolls up, he can scroll all the way up to make the image full screen height size.

What kid of steps I need to take to make it behave the way I imagined?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, please find answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the the general Idea.
Activity:

```
public void setupMovingBar(final Boolean full) {

    final Display dWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    appBarLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int heightPx = dWidth.getHeight();
            if (!full) {
                heightPx = dWidth.getHeight() - (dWidth.getHeight() * 1 / 3);
            }

            setAppBarOffset(heightPx);

        }
    });
}


private void setAppBarOffset(int offsetPx) {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    behavior.onNestedPreScroll(clContent, appBarLayout, null, 0, offsetPx, new int[]{0, 0});
}
```